# Ĉu traduku aŭ ĉu ne traduku varmarkon? Should trade marks / brand names be translated?

Tags: translation, culture

Ŝajnas al mi, ke en Esperanto pli da origine fremdlingvaj (ne esperantaj) varmarkoj estas tradukataj en Esperanton, ol kutimas esti tradukata en la respektiva cellingvo en aliaj lingvoj.

Ĉu mia impreso pravas? Ĉu mi ankaŭ faru tiel, kiam mi uzas origine neesperantan varmarkon en esperanta teksto aŭ parolado?

---

It seems to me like in Esperanto, more originally foreign-language (non-Esperanto) trade marks and brand names are being translated into Esperanto than is usual to translate to the respective target language in other languages.

Is that so or have my observations be biased? Should I do this, too, when using originally non-Esperanto brands in Esperanto texts or speech?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En teksto oni nun ne plu esperantigas varmarkojn. Okazis tia ŝanĝo en Vikipedio, kie antaŭe oni ekzemple havis artikolon "Vindozo", kiu estis alinomita al "Microsoft Windows" (https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows). "Vindozo" fariĝis alidirektilo. La samo por "Linukso" -> "Linux".

Answer (score 2):

Mi opinias ke oni devas traduki varmarkojn *malplej* ofte kiel eble.

Mi diras tion pro tre praktika kialo: imagu se oni tradukus "BitCoin" al "BitMonero". Tamen, ja ekzistas cifereca mon-unuo nomata "Monero" (ĝi havas Esperantan nomon!). Tiam oni kreus grandan konfuzon, tute sennecese.

Foje oni bezonas traduketon aŭ prononcan klarigon/simpligon, sed ĝenerale oni evitu tro rompi la originalan nomon.